# jQuery validation error "not defined"

Tags: javascript, jquery

When validating the jQuery I receive the followers 2 errors: "'$' was used before it was defined." & "'window' was used before it was defined." What does this mean & how do I remove these errors?

```js
var lastScrollTop = 0;
$(window).scrollTop(0);

$(window).on('scroll', function() {
    var header = $('header');
    var content = $('content');
    var headerBg = $('.header-bg');
    var headerCnt = $('.header-content');
    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var dynHeaderVisible = false;
  
    if (lastScrollTop > scrollTop) {
      if (scrollTop <= 400) {
        headerBg.css("height", 0);
        headerCnt.css('color', 'white');
      } else {
        headerBg.css("height", 80);
        headerCnt.css("height", 80);
        headerCnt.css('color', 'black');
      }
    } else {
      // Down
      if (scrollTop > 350) {
        console.log ("hi");
        headerCnt.css("height", 0);
        headerBg.css("height", 0);
      }
    }
    
    lastScrollTop = scrollTop;
});

$.fn.isOnScreen = function(){
    var element = this.get(0);
    var bounds = element.getBoundingClientRect();
    return bounds.top < window.innerHeight && bounds.bottom > 0;
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size:1em;
  font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, Sans-serif;
  }
 a {
    background:transparent;
    border:none;
    letter-spacing:0.15em;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    transition: .3s color;
 transition: .3s height;
 }


header {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  height: 80px;
  width: 100%;
}

header ul {
  z-index: 20;
}

.header-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.header-bg,
.header-content {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.header-bg {
  z-index: 100;
  color: gray;
  background-color: white;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  transition: .3s height;
  height: 0;
}

.header-content {
  z-index: 200;
  transition: .3s color;
  color: white;
  background-color: transparent;
  height: 80px;
  transition: .3s height;
  overflow: hidden;
  list-style: none;
}

.logo {
    position: absolute;
    left: 47%;
 color: inherit;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    padding: 18px;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size:.8em;
    letter-spacing:0.05em;
 transition: .3s color;
 }

content {
  display: block;
  height: 2000px;
  background-color: orange;
}

.stage {
    color: #fff;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: white;
 border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    font-size: 48px;
 height: 200px;
 width: 100%;
}

.stage-0 {
    background: grey;
    height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src= "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <div class="header-wrapper">
    <div class="header-bg"></div>
    <div class="header-content">
      <ul>
        <li>
        <a href="" class="logo">Logo </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
<content>
<div class="stage stage-0">1</div>
<div class="stage stage-2">3</div>
<div class="stage stage-4">5</div>
<div class="stage stage-6">7</div>
<div class="stage stage-8">9</div>
<div class="stage stage-10">11</div>
<div class="stage stage-12">13</div>
<div class="stage stage-14">15</div>
<div class="stage stage-16">17</div>
<div class="stage stage-18">19</div>
<div class="stage stage-20">21</div>
<div class="stage stage-22">23</div>
</content>
```

Comment: Your `<script>` tag should be in the html `<head>` or `<body>`.  I'm not sure that is true from the code provided.

Comment: The errors mean that you're making jquery calls before the reference appears on the page. Make sure the jquery reference appears before any code that relies on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should wrap your Javascript in a 'document onready' block. Something like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // your code here...
});
```

This will ensure that both the page and jQuery are loaded and ready before your code runs.